# Java List/Set performance

Tags: java, performance, list, collections, set

I must work with a `Collection`, and I am not sure about using a `List` or a `Set`. This collection must be sorted, but not by the order of insertion but for another one, so each time a new item is added, a `Comparator` should be executed in order to reorder the `Collection`. So, for this reason, an `ArrayList` could be the best option.

Removing objects from that `Collection` must be possible too, furthermore, I would really appreciate using `removeIf` method, so a `Set` would be the best option here.

Getting and iterating over the `Collection` will be the most repeated scenario, so it must have a good performance in this scenario.

Seeing that, I think that a `Set` would be a good decision, however, I was thinking about converting the `Set` into a `List` when adding items, then, once the list has been resorted, converting it back to a `Set`. Is it bad performing? What do you think?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want your `Collection` to be able to contain duplicate elements?

Comment: *so each time a new item is added, a Comparable should be executed in order to reorder the Collection. So, for this reason, an ArrayList could be the best option* - No. Actually, an `ArrayList` is sorted by insertion order, which you don't want. A `Set` is sorted each time you ad an element, so it would be the best option here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with this list? Then we might be able to advise you better

Comment: what do you think about TreeSet?

Comment: Have you looked at [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)? And why do you need a `Set` to use `removeIf`? It is a default method of all `Collection`s. Converting between list and set is defintely not helpful, as you'd loose the ordering (except you convert to `TreeSet`, of course, but then you do not need a list anyway).

Comment: The problem of TreeSet is that iterating over it is slower than over an ArrayList or LinkedHashSet. The Collection should not have duplicated elements.

Comment: May be relevant: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on how you fill and use your collection and performance of which operation is the most important.

Do you fill the collection with items at once? Or add new elements from time to time? Does the performance of adding elements matter? Or only the iteration performance is important?

If performance is critical, it might make sense to implement a few solutions and compare their performance using a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

I personally don't believe that iteration performance of a `TreeSet` is that much worse that `ArrayList`s or `LinkedList`s or `LinkedHashMap`s. Especially compared to linked data structures. Iteration on a tree should not be that different in the performance. But I have no data, so this is just a belief here.

Below are two implementation ideas.

First, if you load a lot of data at once and then add new items rather seldom, load the data into an `ArrayList` and sort it using `Collections.sort`. If you need to add another item do a binary search (`Collections.binarySearch`) and insert the element at the corresponding position. Wrap it all in a custom `List` implementation and you're good to go.

Next, if you fill the collection with the data "in the beginning" and then the collection is hardly modified, you may simply cache the iteration order in an `ArrayList`. Every time the collection is modified, reset this list and. When iteration is requested and the list is not `null`, just use it, otherwise first fill it in the order of the sorted set.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have bulk inserts during which you would need no sorting, TreeSet is fine. Simply measure *both* solutions.

With TreeSet inserting already ordered items, like rereading a set from disk, performs bad in that even a balanced tree, will have a bit too large depth. That however can be remedied.

For better performance you might go for a **B-tree** (needs 3rd party code) instead of the binary TreeSet. *Measure that too, as typically a facet such as deletion with rebalancing might be done suboptimally.*